# Android Studio: Cant run cloned github project with samples because I am missing a gradle

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle, project

I cloned this [repository](https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu) from github and opened it as a new project.
The project view shows no gradle and I cant run the provided samples.

How can I create or add a gradle to the project and run the samples?

[image: Project View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository directory what you have mentioned is not an android project.

This is the URL for that wheel sample

[Android-Wheel-Menu](https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu/tree/master/wheel-menu-sample)

and also it is developed in Eclipse. So better download it from browser. then load it from Android STUDIO.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the repository as a zip-file. Unpacked it. And went to File > Import Project > wheel-menu-samples. Before I always imported the whole repository

Answer (score 0):

What you cloned is not an Android application but a library for Android applications. Thus, it's not intended to be run standalone which is why you don't find a *build.gradle*. You need to create a new Android project and then follow the steps under "Usage" which explain how to integrate it in a project.

This library is marked as deprecated, so you might want consider using another one.